# Unity Project Settings will not open. How to fix?

Tags: unity-game-engine, settings

I am in Unity2d version 2020.1.8f. I go to Edit>Project Settings... and nothing happens. Clicking Edit>Preferences... and Edit>Shortcuts.. works fine, but whenever I try Edit>Project Settings... it just fails to open the window. I have tried switching versions, originally I was on 2020.1.7f and I have tried multiple restarts for unity. There are no error messages or anything.

Comment: Reset the layout to default. It maybe off screen

Comment: Yes thank you, this worked I should have tried that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might have to do with the layout resizing the window. Try to change the layout to default. That just worked for me